# How to generate a certificate for AWS EC2 instance part of AWS ECS ( Docker)

Tags: ssl, docker, amazon-ec2

We have a domain and our web-app uses AWS ECS docker containers and we have 3 of such EC2 instances which host the docker containers. Since the web-app is https - the socket request we make to the docker containers also have to be https to avoid mixed content error.

We already have a certificate from Let's Encrypt for our web-app - how do I go about certificates for individual EC2 instances which are a part of AWS ECS cluster ?

Edit 1 : our web-app is hosted on AWS and the docker containers launch a node https server

Comment: Any particular reason why ELB cannot be used in front of the ECS nodes and offload cert at the ELB?

Comment: We have not used ELB. this seems to be a concept we need to explore. thank you @rockcode

Comment: @rockcode : how do these individual EC2 device access that certificate - since each of them host a https server

Comment: You can install the cert on the host and mount the dir to the containers and should be able to configure https server to load them. But, now you'll have to have load balancer in front of the containers to load balance the traffic since ELBs cannot load balance to EC2 servers. Other option to look at is application load balancer, but I think you'll have to offload ssl at the ALB itself. Not sure if that's an option for you.